# Intellij 14: Unable to create working repository from git "bare" repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-bare

When I try to check out a Git non-working repository (created with the -bare option), Intellij doesn't create a working local repository but just clone the .git folder!

So my question is how do you create a local working Git repository from a server repository?

The workaround I've found is to clone it manually but this sollution is no very convenient.

Some tools like Git Extensions asks if you want to create a personnal repository or a Public one but i can't find this option in Intellij (version 14.0.3)

Thanks for help!

Comment: What exactly did you do? git init --bare on the server and then?

Comment: @jsexpert, the --bare repo was created by one collegue from an existing project whith the git init --bare on the server.  So the project used to create the --bare repo was correctly populated with java classes, etc.

Comment: You know that git init --bare is creating repository without file system. The content of the repository is actually the content of the .git folder

Comment: Yes and that's exactly my problem.  A --bare repo is usually installed on a server to which developers push their changes.  So the --bare doesn't have the source files and i have no problem with that.  But, when a new developer arrive in the team, he should be able to create a developer repository from a --bare repository.  Application such as GitExtention offer this possibility.  It seems that Intellij's clone option is only copying file present in the remote repo and doesn't care to recreate the folder hierarchy.